# parametrize method with passing and expected failing in pytest without skipping

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I want to test a Python function via Pytest.
With the parametrize decorator I pass 2 expected passing and one expecting failing (via ValueError in the method).

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("input_nr, expected", [
    (123.456, (123, 456)),
    (456.789, (456, 789)),
    pytest.param("123.123", (123, 123),  marks=pytest.mark.xfail(raises=ValueError, strict=True))]
                         )
def test_my_func(input_nr, expected):
    res = my_func(input_nr)
    print("\n" + str(res))
    assert res == expected
```

From the docs of pytest, I think to understod it right, I have to use `pytest.param` for adding expected failing tests.

But if I run this in pytest, only the two passing runs are passed and the expected failing run was skipped/ignored.

What do I have to change in parametrize to fail successfully?

Answer (score 0):

xfail will not report a pass. So my test report won't be showing the expected result I hoped for.

So my way will be to handle expected expection in the test code, not via parametrize.

Comment: The expected behaviour was in the docs all along: https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/example/parametrize.html#parametrizing-conditional-raising

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test your function to fail for specific inputs then write a function that tests exactly those cases separately.

I needed to assume what your `my_func` does, but it could look something like this:

```py
import pytest


def my_func(num: float):
    if not isinstance(num, float):
        raise ValueError("Wrong format")
    return tuple([int(n) for n in str(num).split(".")])

@pytest.mark.parametrize("input_nr, expected", [
    (123.456, (123, 456)),
    (456.789, (456, 789))
]
                         )
def test_my_func_valid(input_nr, expected):
    """Test function for valid input"""
    res = my_func(input_nr)
    print("\n" + str(res))
    assert res == expected


@pytest.mark.parametrize("input_nr, expected", [("123.123", (123, 123))])
def test_my_func_invalid(input_nr, expected):
    """Test if a ValueError is thrown"""
    with pytest.raises(ValueError) as e:
        my_func(input_nr)

    assert str(e.value) == "Wrong format"
```

Comment: Just learned today, that you can do it like the pytest docs say:
https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/example/parametrize.html#parametrizing-conditional-raising
I was just stucking on xfail itself...